Understanding Non-parametric Probability Density Estimation
I'm trying to deepen my understanding of non-parametric probability density estimation methods and their relation to parametric methods. I'd like to verify if my current understanding is correct:

In parametric methods, we typically express a probability density function as $p(x;\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a fixed, finite-dimensional parameter vector.

In non-parametric methods, we often simply write $p(x)$. However, I believe a more accurate representation would be $p(x;\phi(D))$, where $D$ represents the observed data
$\phi(D)$ is a flexible, data-dependent parameterization

The key differences are:
Parametric: $\theta \in \Theta$, where $\dim(\Theta) = k$ (fixed)
Non-parametric (practical): $\phi_n(D) \in \Phi_n$, where $\dim(\Phi_n) = k_n$ (data-dependent)
Non-parametric (theoretical): $\phi(D) \in \Phi$, where $\dim(\Phi) = \infty$

In non-parametric methods, even when $\phi(D)$ is finite for a given dataset, it has the potential to grow without bound as more data is added. There's no predefined limit to this growth.

Non-parametric methods, even when using finite representations, are typically formulated in a way that embeds them in an infinite-dimensional space.

We can think of a sequence of function spaces $\{\Phi_n\}$, where:


For any finite $n$, $\dim(\Phi_n) < \infty$
$\Phi_1 \subset \Phi_2 \subset \Phi_3 \subset \cdots \subset \Phi$
$\Phi = \bigcup_n \Phi_n$ is infinite-dimensional

Examples:

Kernel Density Estimation (KDE):
$p(x;\phi(D)) = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K(\frac{x-X_i}{h})$
k-Nearest Neighbors (k-NN):
$p(x;\phi(D)) \propto \frac{k}{nV(x)}$
Gaussian Process Regression:
$p(y|x,\phi(D)) = \mathcal{N}(\mu(x), \sigma^2(x))$
Is this understanding correct? Are there any misconceptions or additional important points I should consider to fully grasp the nature of non-parametric methods and their relation to parametric approaches?
